# JavaScript callback to an instance of an object 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a bit of a pickle.

I've created a sweet javascript plugin That worked fine. But then I decided that if I want multiple versions of the plugin running I'll have to create multiple instances of it.

But then... I noticed something, my callbacks don't callback. I've narrowed the culprit down to the fact that I can no longer reference `this` due to the script needing to be referenced.

My question is this (code follows). how do you reference an instance of an object in Javascript, as `this` doesn't work.

Here's the code snippets.

**Previously**

The code scaffold **used to** look like this, and it worked with no problems:

`var list = (function () { //code }());`

But, so I can instantiate my object, I changed it like so:

```
 var list = (function () { //code });
```

And so as previously I would call list.init(); directly, now I create a new instance of it:

`var test = new list("test");`

before calling it.

There are several functions in the list object, one fires off an ajax request by filling up an object with data and then passing this object to a script that handles requests. In the object is a function that is a callback to this object, lets take a look at that method:

```
   makeTemplateRequest = function () {
    console.log('make template request called');
    var send = new JaysHelpers.Ajax.sendObject();
    send.page = "/list.html",
    send.request = "widget",
    send.blockNumber = 0,
    send.numberOfItems = 1,
    send.filters = [],
    send.callBack = templateCallback;


    gateKeeper.request({
        speed: "now",
        sendObj: send,
        recur: false            
    });

},
```

The problem is here:

```
     send.callBack = me.templateCallback;
```

This should be referencing a method that the ajax plugin calls back to:

`templateCallback = function(jsonObject, error){ 
//callbackcode 
},`

But instead it is 'undefined'.

I've tried several things, I've tried reserving `this` in the local space of the script as `var me = this;` But that actually reserves a global namespace. I've tried `this.templateCallback` but that is the same as the previous one, Ive tried calling it externally `list.templateCallback` but now the plugin requires instantiating, that doesn't work. I've tried referencing it locally as `templateCallback` but that doesn't work.

Also note, the functions are exposed through:

```
    return {
    init: init,
    callback: callback,
    templateCallback: templateCallback      
};
```

**The Question**

So my question is this, how do I reference `this` instance of an object?

**EDIT**

More complete code:

```
var list = (function () {

"use strict";

var init = function (options) {


    //check and verify data passed in
   // if happy make the call below
    makeTemplateRequest();

},
makeTemplateRequest = function () {
    console.log('make template request called');
    var send = new JaysHelpers.Ajax.sendObject();
    send.page = "/list.html",
    send.request = "widget",
    send.blockNumber = 0,
    send.numberOfItems = 1,
    send.filters = [],
    send.callBack = templateCallback;

    gateKeeper.request({
        speed: "now",
        sendObj: send,
        recur: false            
    });

},
```

`templateCallback = function (html, error) {
            var thisHtml = html || "";
           //do stuff with returned data
        };`

```
return {
    init: init,
    callback: callback,
    templateCallback: templateCallback      
};
```

});

Comment: If you're going to use `new` for creating a new instance, don't `return` from the function. Just set them as properties of `this`. Then you'll have access to them "publicly" just the same

Comment: @Ian: In general good advice, although if you *do* return an object, the one created via `new` is discarded and the one you return is used instead.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Interesting, not sure I knew that. Then again, I've never tried to mix these methodologies :)

Comment: So at the end, i should just return this?

Comment: @Jay: In the end, it's really unclear what you're trying to do. If you can create a small, **complete**, example of what you're trying to do and post it to the question (with correct code formatting), which we call an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) here, that would help. It's never correct to return `this` from a constructor function (although it's harmless). (It can be correct to return `this` from non-constructor functions.)

Comment: @Ian: It's one of the dusty corners of JavaScript. :-)

Comment: Well thats What I was thinking, I tend to only expose methods I need, never the whole plugin. But then again I usually don't code javascript in a way seen here (were you can create new instances of it). Hence why I'm slightly confused.

Comment: Ok, I've tried to add as much relevant code as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code

```
send.callBack = me.templateCallback;
```

will assign the function reference to `send.callBack`, but will do nothing to preserve the value of `me` (which would be `this` during the call to `templateCallback`). To do that, you can use ES5's `Function#bind` (which can be shimmed on older browsers):

```
send.callBack = me.templateCallback.bind(me);
```

`Function#bind` creates a function that, when called, will call the original function with `this` set to the argument you give it.

The reason for this is that when you call a function, the value of `this` within the call is set almost entirely by **how** you called the function, not where the function is defined or what object it's attached to.

More *(on my blog)*:

- [*Mythical methods*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/mythical-methods.html)
- [*You must remember `this`*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/04/you-must-remember-this.html)

Comment: But won't it preserve `this` as long as you call it correctly? Such as `test.templateCallback()`? I think the problem is how `templateCallback` is defined - note how the `templateCallback` is referenced in the `return` - as a local variable, not a property of `me` (or `this` or whatever)

Comment: @Ian: If you do `test.templateCallback()`, within `templateCallback`, `this` will be `test`. But that's almost certainly **not** how the code calling `send.callBack` calls it.

Comment: Crap crap crap, I'm just confusing myself. I know how to handle `this` correctly (as you've shown), I'm just confusing variables and stuff. Disregard what I'm blabbering about

Comment: Interesting I will try the bind.  @Ian test.templateCallback() will work as intended. The problem is when the code itself tries to call itself: this.templateCallback which, because its an instance will return the global `this`. Thanks for the input both, will give your blogs a ready an mess about with it! Will accept answer accordingly.

Comment: Just so you know thats working perfectly, the second blog explained alot, thanks for the help.